# How to design a Db table for attendance

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2007, schema

I am currently working on a school management system but can't seem to figure out the best way to design my student attendance table.

**INFO**

School is for 14 weeks and class holds 5 times a week. Students in the school can be up to 2000 per term. Meaning attendance can be up to `14 x 5 x 2000 = 140, 000` per term.

I am developing the application for a desktop using `VB.Net` and `MS Access`.

**PROGRESS SO FAR**

I have so far designed something that I am skeptic about.

table name: attendance

```
_____________________________________________
| id |std_id | att_week | att_date |  status |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| 1  | 0001  |    1     |29/9/2015 |  yes    |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| 2  | 0002  |    1     |29/9/2015 |  yes    |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

I easily found out that designing it like this can easily yield `140, 000` rows in a term.

I also thought of making the week days as column names, that will easily result in `14 x 5 = 70 columns`.

What is the best way to design this said table.

Comment: I am no expert of MS or vb but if you are worried about size then what if you record absent students that way your table size would be negligible. So assuming everyone attends the school in a term you will see no records in that table!

Comment: @TechMaze That's something, I will consider the idea.

Comment: Go though -> [1](http://www.academia.edu/7760318/STUDENTS_ATTENDANCE_MANAGEMENT_SYSTEM_MINI_PROJECT_REPORT_MASTER_OF_COMPUTER_APPLICATIONS),[2](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/451723/database-for-student-attendance-management-system)

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ Please elaborate

Comment: @Diamond both link itself well explained,So what the point of elaboration here

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ Sorry, I just found out that they are links

Answer (score 0):

Friend I think you should construct your table like this:
Table would accept only the absentees

```
id     student_id    class    date
________________________________________
1          11          7a    11/11/2020
2          21          6b    10/12/2020
```

and so on.....
You could easily retrieve details like
1]  total absentees per class
2] total absent of a student in date range
3] Per day report of attendance of student can be easily prepared based on this data

**ALSO** this would be extremly fast due to less number of record and if you index on `class_id` and  and partition tables in specified `date` range.

Thank You!